# Who is "financially speaking" the poorest superhero in the Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Generally, it is shown that Peter Parker struggles to make ends meet, so for me Spider-Man is the poorest superhero in Marvel Universe.

Peter Parker is shown to do odd jobs like pizza delivery to earn money. Also, he sells Spider-Man pictures. Lives in somewhat broken homes and so on.

Is there any other superhero showing greater signs of poverty than Spider-Man?

(P.S.: No mentions of characters like Thor who are from different realm/universe/planet and have no use or requirement of earth based money.)

Comment: In the Marvel Universe, poverty is relative. Peter Parker could have been wealthy years ago if he had leveraged any of the half a dozen technologies he created as Spider-Man. His poverty was a contrivance of the writers to maintain his role as a character whose luck was always bad and never managed to get a break. Actually poor superheroes are relatively rare. If I were to name a couple of heroes who never seem to ever have a job or regular paychecks: Cloak, Dagger, Rocket Racer, The Prowler, Blade, Man-Thing, Doctor Strange, White Tiger, almost any X-man except Angel...off the top of my head.

Comment: @Thaddeus If going by X-Men, Prof. X is one of the richest superhero in Marvel and DC universe combined.

Comment: Professor X is no longer among the living (at the moment)...

Comment: I immediately thought of Swamp Thing -- I know he's DC, but there must be some equivalents in the Marvel universe who are elementals/spirits/ghosts and simply have no interest in material possessions. Alternatively, I'm sure there are some ascetic martial-artist type heroes who deliberately keep themselves poor (although I can't bring any to mind at the moment).

Comment: Do we actually know any superheroes bank balance? The answer is going to be an opinion based on whoever _looks_ the most homeless. The OP even asks specifically for someone showing _signs of poverty_.

Comment: @Daft It is not opinion based. But you can easily deduce from Peter Parker's lifestyle and behavior that he is obviously poor. I am asking for obvious things not opinion based. Captain America is not super rich, but doesn't even show signs of poverty. It is so obvious.

Comment: I reckon this is too broad to be answerable. We can all speculate, but the entire Marvel universe is big, and the stories don’t often provide details of how each hero lives, day-to-day.

Comment: "But you can easily deduce from Peter Parker's lifestyle and behavior that he is obviously poor." You've obviously not read *Superior Spider-Man*. While Peter was a broke high school student when he was introduced, he has not exactly remained so.

Comment: What's your definition/tolerance of poverty? Those who live in the Savage Land live without any sort of technology (except when guests bring it in). Wolverine has lived for extended periods on nothing but what he could hunt/forage in the woods. The Morlocks live in the sewers. Gateway lives by himself in the Australian outback wearing nothing but a loincloth.

Comment: Beyond not receiving any paychecks, the lifestyles of those characters don't even involve money in any appreciable way.

Comment: Cloak and dagger are homeless runaway teens. Can't get more poor than that

Comment: And the more locks of xmen comics. They live in sewers.

Comment: @Thaddeus What about Captain Marvel Junior, with his day job selling newspapers? Or Wonder Wart-Hog, also in the news business?

Comment: If we are going by MCU characters I'm going to say Scott Lang. How? The question states that only characters whose backgrounds are affected by lack of resources can count, and Scott's lack of resources affects him the most. He is a semi-reformed career burgler (a career that hasn't worked out for him very well,) whose background prevents him from holding down a job and from seeing his daughter.

Comment: Compare that to Luke Cage who lost his jobs sweeping floors and washing dishes, Jessica Jones who can't afford to repair her apartment, Matt Murdock who can't afford to keep the lights on in his office, or the aforementioned Spider-man. None of them seem to be affected much by their financial insecurity, only Scott.

Answer (score 10):

Being as this has used the Marvel Cinematic Universe tag as one of the tags, I will answer with a Marvel Cinematic Universe answer.

We haven't seen that many superheroes in the Marvel Cinematic Universe so far. Including the films and TV shows, as of March 2015 it would seem that the most financially insecure hero would be Dr Bruce Banner, who has no home that we know of, has been on the run from various agencies for a number of years (and as such has few possessions) and has no stable financial income.

The last time we saw him was in the post-credits scene of *Iron Man 3*, which gave us little to no information on his current situation - before that it was in *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* which showed us a man living in hiding in an out of the way area of the world. In comparison to his team mates (a billionaire, a prince and three SHIELD employees), it would appear that he is the worst off, at least from a financial perspective.

Another potential candidate from the Marvel Cinematic Universe is Dethlok, but being as his history and current situation are a lot more uncertain, it would be hard to say for sure.

Comment: Bruce Banner is one of the smartest humans in the marvel universe. He looks dishevelled a lot of the time because it's the condition the Hulk leaves him. And at this stage in the MCU he is an employee of SHIELD and a close friend of Tony Stark. I don't think he's broke.

Comment: Also you say _has no stable financial income_. This is just an assumption on your part, there's no way to know for sure.

Comment: @Daft We have no evidence that he has ever been an employee of SHIELD or if he was that he has found a new job since the fall of SHIELD, and no knowledge of his financial situation since *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* showed us that he was in hiding, and as such unlikely to be drawing attention to himself. He may not require much money to survive or even thrive when surrounded by The Avengers, but he would still seem to be the most likely candidate for "poorest superhero in the Marvel Cinematic Universe".

Comment: He is friends with Stark, and Stark knows his situation. I don't think he'd let one of the Avengers wander the streets homeless. But ultimately, it's exactly like you say: we have _no knowledge of his financial situation_. Absolutely none. It's all opinion and conjecture.

Comment: @Daft Even if Stark homes and feeds him, he is still likely the poorest hero that we have seen so far in the MCU because there just aren't that many heroes we need to compare him to. The other likely contender (bar Dethlok) is Falcon, who is ex-Military and working in a support centre for other veterans, but at least we know he has a job and a home. Bruce Banner, at least up until The Battle of New York, lived as a nomad, and as such it would make sense for him to be the poorest. It is conjecture, but it is based on solid information and logical reasoning.

Comment: “Bruce Banner, at least up until The Battle of New York, lived as a nomad, and as such it would make sense for him to be the poorest.” — Not necessarily. He might have loads of cash, just not in a bank account because he’s living off the grid.

Comment: And the last we see of him in the Avengers, he’s getting into a sports car with one of the the richest people in the world.

Comment: “We have no evidence that he has ever been an employee of SHIELD” — absolutely. Employees don’t normally have to be brought to work with the aid of a SWAT team.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite "He might have loads of cash, just not in a bank account because he’s living off the grid." If he had loads of cash, he wouldn't have muttered to himself about getting paid up front next time when the little girl escapes though the window at the start of *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble*.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: he might have done. He might have a very deep and strong sense of financial justice. Maybe Avengers 2 will actually be all about Banner avenging that little girl’s financial slight on him.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are a considerable number of heroes who live "off the grid" (Bruce Banner springs to mind), I think we can go one better and start looking at indebtedness.

Several years ago, [Hercules](http://marvel.com/universe/Hercules_%28Heracles%29) was sued by the Constrictor for the use of "excessive force" in his capture. The result was that he was found owing $168 million in punitive damages. Having handed over his entire fortune, he still needed to find gainful employment (with Damage Control, as it happens) as a means of making his court-ordered repayments.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It doesn't beat "negative" wealth, but Gateway would be a close second - he's an Aborigine who lives off the land. I don't think he even has a permanent hut anywhere.